# FR-4 discoloring in reflow oven

Tags: pcb, reflow

Is it normal for exposed (no solder mask) FR-4 to blacken during reflow? We're using a fairly ordinary profile with a max at 233C,  about 5 minutes total and only about 60 seconds above 200C. I realize FR-4 has a max temp of 130C+/- long term but I thought it should be able to take a reflow cycle.

It turns from bright green to almost black. It's darker in areas exposed on both sides, not quite so bad over large copper floods. Electrically everything is fine and the boards are functional, and the solder looks great down to 20 mil pitch QFNs.  The gold connectors and traces aren't discolored so I don't think it's something else on the board or in the oven fuming off, and there was no smoke.

Are we doing something wrong, or is solder mask simply mandatory for reflow on FR-4?

Edit:

[image]

The SMA connectors were hand soldered on after the fact and the white stuff is rosin from that (doesn't clean well off the blackened surface).

Comment: What is the actual board temperature you measured?

Comment: heat source ? and method of flow? forced or convection? makes a huge difference to heat absorption and profile and temp of each component's surface as well as material type of FR4

Comment: As Tony Stewart notes, the material used makes a difference: FR-4 simply means the material is flame retardent. Are you buying the material to one of the IPC4101/??? standards?

Comment: _"It turns from bright green to almost black."_ - None of the FR4 PCBs I've seen are bright green, they are invariably a dull semi-translucent beige colour. What's usually green is the soldermask. Can you post pictures of your PCB (preferably before and after the blackening)?

Comment: Please post your complete temperature profile.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.   Tony, W5VO: First let me admit up front it's a repurposed toaster oven, so not forced air.  The thermocouple is positioned about 1cm above and 1cm off the edge of the board.  Peter:  The blank boards were from Advanced Circuits (www.4pcb.com) and it was their standard FR-4.   Glenn:  Here is the profile (measured):

Comment: Temperature profile (measured):   0 sec = 29.6C;  30 sec = 46.6C;  60 sec = 91.9C;  90 sec = 130.6C;  120 sec = 158.9C; 150sec = 177.3C;  180 sec = 193.2C; 210 sec = 208.5C;  240 sec = 221.8C;  270 sec = 233.2C, power off open and vent.  The darkening was noticeable at 210 sec.

Comment: Marcelm:  I'll try to get some photos up,  don't know to get them here so it might be a flickr link.

Comment: Just realized the top heating element isn't shrouded.  Direct radiative heat transfer to the board making it heat much faster than the air near it?

Comment: Frankly, that looks horribly damaged. How about a photo of your thermcouple in situ? If the board has been grossly overheated the adhesion of the traces will be compromised- it looks like the wide trace has been lifted on the lower right side of the PCB (BNC connector?). Yes, the emissivity of a shiny thermocouple will be much less than 1, and it has a path of heat down the leads.

Comment: I have heated them up with a heatgun while soldering large SMT components. Never seen any color change remotely like what you are showing. I am suspecting that you are way over temp.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany,  I agree about the appearance, and it was surprising that it worked well at 4 GHz (the chip is a MOSFET based RF switch).  However the trace lift was due to me getting the SMA connector in crooked and manually reseating the connector level using the time dishonored "heat one leg, shove and repeat" method - wasn't being careful because I assumed like you the board was toast.